# Ranking by Group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rank

I have a table with one column as follows:

```
name
-------
Michael
Michael
Michael
Michael
John
John
John
Alex
Alex
```

I need to rank them to give:

```
name    | rank
--------|------
Michael |1
Michael |2
Michael |3
Michael |4
John    |1
John    |2
John    |3
Alex    |1
Alex    |2
```

How can I perform that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing in mysql that lets you do this directly, but you can hack it in:

```
SET @prev := null;

SET @cnt := 1;

SELECT name, IF(@prev <> name, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := name
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY name
```

This sort of thing is easier done in your client app, using the same basic logic.

Comment: Because of null value the rank start from 2 (2,3,4,5) for Micheal. If I set @prev := 'string', the result is correct. Thanks.

Comment: Marc, Please check out by bellow comment. it's not that much hard to do it in MySql

Comment: This doesn't reliably work, because the order of evaluation for reading @prev and writing it (within a single SELECT) is not defined. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 6):

Simple,

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
rank MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (name,rank)) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES
('Michael'),('Michael'),('John'),('Alex'),('Michael'),('John');

SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY name,rank;
```

Comment: yes, and now you've got a simple sequence of numbers. OP wants a sequence PER name, not per table.

Comment: It will works in a same way he wants, it will add a sequence as per the names only. just try it out.

Comment: This is such a great trick.  I've come to Stack Overflow for this specific answer a half dozen times.

Comment: This is both obscure and brilliant! It can also be done with a temporary table for a real world use.

Comment: what if the table has a primary key Id column with auto increment too?

Comment: Great work around but it is inexcusable that MySQL does not have a working `Rank()` function so we have to resort to such a weird solution (note if you dont include `ENGINE=MyISAM` it wont work).