# Merging two rows in one row - dirty and slow procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, join, merge

I have here little issue with mysql query. I know how to fix it, but I wanted to know if there is quicker and nicer solution. *(I'm sure there is.)*

This is how my table should look.

```
TABLE logger

id  keys    text            type_id
 1  2csi    consectetuer    1
 2  3vjk    lorem ipsum     2
 3  2csi    consectetuer    1
 4  3vjk    lorem ipsum     2
 5  j49a    consectetuer    1
```

My logger get crazy and logged values key and text as individual rows. In 90% with correct type_id.

```
TABLE broken_logger

id  keys    text            type_id
 1          consectetuer    1
 2  0a2v                    0
 3          lorem ipsum     2
 4  2csi                    1
 5          consectetuer    1
 6  3vjk                    2
 7          lorem ipsum     2
 8  3vjk                    2
 9          dolor sit amet  2
10          consectetuer    1
11  2csi                    1
12          lorem ipsum     2
13          nibh euismod    1
14          consectetuer    1
15  7kl4                    0
16  j49a                    1
17          Ut wisi enim    1
18          volutpat        2
19          sed diam        1
20  7kl4                    0
```

Text is for ordering or merging useless, it's used for later analytics. So it must be joined with key that has same type_id. Type_id == 0 is error, it should be ignored. It is only in rows with keys, no text row has type_id = 0.

I tried JOINS and UNION ALL but I honestly don't know how to use (OUTER|RIGHT|LEFT|CROSS) JOIN to merge one key with one text. I'm always getting for each text also each key with same type_id. And I don't want to combine all of them. Just merge rows with text and without keys with rows with key but without text.

So I tried this dirty procedure:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE num INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE pid INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE pkey VARCHAR(4) DEFAULT '';

-- all type_ids
WHILE k <= 2 DO

    -- select numer of keys for this type_id 
    SELECT count(*) INTO num
        FROM broken_logger
        WHERE type_id = k
        AND text = ''
        AND key != '';

    WHILE i < num DO

        -- select only one key for update and key id for later deletion
        SELECT id, key INTO pid, pkey
        FROM broken_logger
        WHERE type_id = k
        AND text = ''
        AND key != ''
        LIMIT 1;

        -- update only one text entry with one key
        UPDATE broken_logger
        SET key = pkey
        WHERE type_id = k
        AND text != ''
        AND key = ''
        LIMIT 1;

        -- delete used key
        DELETE broken_logger
        WHERE id = pid;

        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    SET i = 0;
    SET k = k + 1;
END WHILE;
END;
```

It's working but it's uneffective and very slow. And I tried so many things that I think I'm running in circles. Can someone point me or help with JOINS/UNIONS to get this task done cleaner?

Comment: I reckon you fixed your logger, so you need to run this only once. Just let it run slow and inefficient (if it is working, it is effective), then throw the whole thing away.

Comment: Can you explain how the text is chosen for a particular id?

Comment: Text doesn't affects type_id. It's predefined action which is than logged. For this situation there is no need to have right key for right text because there is no way to pair them exactly as they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, keys and texts occur sequentially by type (though different types might be mixed so that a type 1 key might be followed by a type 2 text, then type 1 text), and you just need an efficient way to join them together.

To solve this, I used a MySQL rank function I found on another Stack Overflow question ([Ranking by Group in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361364/ranking-by-group-in-mysql)) that allowed me to rank by type id.  It worked by ordering the results by `type_id`, and then incrementing a `cnt` until a the `type_id` changed.  I created two tables for key and text from queries that used the ranking function, and then joined them together to produce the result below.

**SQL**

```
SET @prev := 0;
SET @cnt := 1;

CREATE TABLE sequentialkeys AS (
  SELECT  id, `key`, type_id,
        IF(@prev <> type_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := type_id
  FROM    logger
  WHERE type_id != 0 AND `key` != ''
  ORDER BY type_id, id
 );

SET @prev := 0;
SET @cnt := 1;

CREATE TABLE sequentialtext AS (
  SELECT  id, `text`, type_id,
        IF(@prev <> type_id, @cnt := 1, @cnt := @cnt + 1) AS rank, @prev := type_id
  FROM    logger
  WHERE type_id != 0 AND `text` != ''
  ORDER BY type_id, id
 );

SET @cnt := 0;
SELECT @cnt := @cnt + 1 AS id, a.*
FROM (
  SELECT k.key, t.text, t.type_id 
  FROM sequentialkeys AS k
  INNER JOIN sequentialtext AS t ON t.type_id = k.type_id AND t.rank = k.rank
  ORDER BY t.id
 ) AS a
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3f4e/8)

**Result**

```
ID  KEY     TEXT            TYPE_ID
1   2csi    consectetuer    1
2   3vjk    lorem ipsum     2
3   2csi    consectetuer    1
4   3vjk    lorem ipsum     2
5   j49a    consectetuer    1
```

- I couldn't create a temporary in SQLFiddle, but you can certainly do that instead of creating permanent ones.  Otherwise just drop `sequentialkeys` and `sequentialtext`.
- I edited my answer to preserve the ordering in case this was a requirement.

Comment: Thank you. I used your sql and subjectively it worked faster. I'll make some benchmark tests this week. I hope it's okay if I accept your answer after this.