# Display each row one by one from each category one by one using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following table structure: basically it is grouping by agency_id.

```
 id    agency_id    price         type
 1      1001           10000       A 
 2      1002           13000       B
 3      1001           16000       C
 4      1003           11000       A
 5      1002           12000       C
 6      1003           9000        D
 7      1001           15000       A
 8      1002           12000       A
```

i want to display it as following

```
 id    agency_id     price        
 1      1001         10000        
 2      1002         13000        
 4      1003         11000        

 3      1001         16000        
 5      1002         12000   
 6      1003         11000
```

i am using the following code, but its showing all the properties from 1 agency, then 2nd agency and so on.

```
ORDER BY
  CASE properties.agency_id
      WHEN 1001 THEN 1
      WHEN 1002 THEN 2
      WHEN 1003 THEN 3
  END
```

but its not giving me the desire results. any help will be apriciated

Regards,

Comment: As you show it the desired order is arbitrary?which 1001,or 1002,or 1003 from all that?

Comment: How have you decided to pair ids (124, 356) rather than (154, 326), (126, 354) or (156, 324)?

Comment: actually i want to pick 1st row from 1st agency, then 1st row from 2nd agency, then 1st row from third agency, then 2nd row from 1st agency, 2nd row from 2nd agency, 2nd row from 3rd agency and so on.

Comment: First, second, etc.  .... Is that defined by the order of the id, i.e., the lowest id is the first?

Comment: no, i want to group it according to the agency_id and then extract 1st row from each agency, then 2nd row from each agency and so on.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - the first record for a given agency is the lowest id, the 2nd record for the same agency is the next largest id, etc. @Barmar answer is what you need to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a solution like the one in [Ranking by Group in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361364/ranking-by-group-in-mysql/18361455#18361455) to add a `rank` column that increments within each group, and put that in a subquery. Then do:

```
SELECT *
FROM (subquery) AS x
ORDER by rank, agency_id
```

Comment: i want to blend the result in such a format that 1st row from 1st agency, 1st row from 2nd agency, 1st row from 3rd agency , then 2nd row from 1st agency, 2nd row from 2nd agency and 3nd row from 2nd agency and so on, how can i achieve this output.