# How to add "index" to group of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a column to my table in MySQL that indexes the occurrence of a group based on an identical `name`.

So I have the `name` and `value` columns below. I want to add the `index` column; it increments, from 1, each time a row with an identical `name` appears.

`name | value | index
 A    | 40    | 1
 A    | 60    | 2
 A    | 80    | 3
 B    | 20    | 1
 B    | 50    | 2
 C    | 10    | 1
 D    | 5     | 1`

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using a trigger, example:http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/before_insert.php

Answer (score 0):

Try variables:

```
set @prev := null
set @index := 1

update yourtable
set index = if(
  @prev = name,
  @index := @index + 1,
  @index := 1
)
order by name, value;
```

But check also: [Ranking by Group in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361364/ranking-by-group-in-mysql)