# How to find MAX Count value for each group separately

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Here is my query

```
SELECT q2.item_code
     , q2.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT
     , q2.count_amount
  FROM 
     ( SELECT i.item_code
            , s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT 
            , count(s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT) count_amount
         FROM sell_delivery_items s 
            , items i
        WHERE s.item_id = i.item_id
        GROUP 
           BY SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT
            , item_code
     ) q2
 order 
    by item_code
     , count_amount desc
```

and the result is

```
item_code   SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT     count_amount
0001        50                       2
0001        100                      1
0002        150                      3
```

I need to show only the highest count_amount row for each item_code group.
I've done the search on some answer but still can't apply to mine.

This is the result i want

```
item_code   SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT     count_amount
0001        50                       2
0002        150                      3
```

How can i do this? thanks you for all answer.

Comment: This is the most frequently asked question under the mysql tag. Sometimes, it's correctly answered too - and it gets a whole page in the manual. But if you're really struggling, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution. Here's mine:

```
SELECT q3.item_code, q3.item_name, substring_index(q3.AMOUNT_LIST, ',' , 1) as most_amount_count, 
substring_index(q3.count_list,',',1) as count_time from

(SELECT q2.item_code, q2.item_name, GROUP_CONCAT(SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT ORDER BY q2.count_amount DESC) as AMOUNT_LIST, 
GROUP_CONCAT(q2.count_amount ORDER BY q2.count_amount desc) as count_list from

    (SELECT  i.item_code, i.ITEM_NAME, s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT , count(s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT) as count_amount
    FROM sell_delivery_items s , items i
    WHERE s.item_id = i.item_id
    GROUP BY SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT, item_code
    order by item_code, count_amount desc
    )  as q2

group by q2.item_code )as q3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested as I do not have MySQL - but something like this should work:

```
 SELECT  q2.item_code, q2.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT, q2.count_amount
 FROM 
(SELECT  i.item_code, s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT , count(s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT)     as count_amount
FROM sell_delivery_items s , items i,  @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
 WHERE s.item_id = i.item_id
 GROUP BY SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT, item_code) as q2
 where rank = 1
order by item_code, count_amount  desc
```

You need to add a "rank" or "row number" functionality to the inner query, then add a filter to the outer query to select only the top ranked row.

Here is another example of ranking in MySQL: [Ranking by Group in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361364/ranking-by-group-in-mysql)

Comment: I've move the "rownum" to inner SELECT and SET rownum =0 before outer SELECT, but it will show only one row and a wrong result.

Comment: you need to do a "rownum" that resets with your GROUP BY - check the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361364/ranking-by-group-in-mysql) , it explains a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT  q2.item_code, q2.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT, max(q2.count_amount)
FROM 
(SELECT  i.item_code, s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT , count(s.SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT) as count_amount
FROM sell_delivery_items s , items i
WHERE s.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT, item_code) as q2
group by q2.item_code
order by count_amount  desc
```

In here `order by item_code, count_amount  desc` you are ordering `item_code` by natural order, a < z, so it's not needed as it's being ordered by the `group by`.

Comment: I've try this, and it will show only first row of first group.

Comment: The SELL_DELIVERY_AMOUNT still showing the wrong value, but the rest is right.